# Opening ArcFM Attribute Editor from ArcObjects

Tags: esri, arcmap

I am trying to get the ArcFM Attribute Editor to open, after selecting a certain feature programatically.
I figured the simplest way would be to grab a hold on a reference to its button, and call its OnClick method. Will that be the best solution? And how do I find the UID of the button? (If there's a general way of finding a button/command UID, I'd appreciate it).

It seems both ESRI and M&M (not the candy...) went to great lengths to supply really bad documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it at the end (with the help of my co-workers here). If anyone will ever be interested in opening the Attribute Editor, here goes:

```
UID uid = new UID();
uid.Value = "mmDesktop.MMAttributeCmd";
ICommandItem commandItem = document.CommandBars.Find(uid, false, false);
commandItem.Command.OnClick();
```

Share and enjoy.